# Using sin() in a formula in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Currently I am trying to implement this formula `pi = n*(sin(180/n));` in xcode. But just writing it like this gives me huge numbers like -12425553 or 23082083. How can I fix it??

I used `int n; double pi;`.

**Update:**

I tried using `M_PI/180` to convert to degrees but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions??

```
pi = n*sin((180/n) * (M_PI/180));
```

By the way I removed the asterisks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

- You define primitives as pointers (you need to remove asterisks)
- You assume that `sin` takes degrees (it takes radians)
- You use integer division (if `sin` indeed took degrees, which it does not, you should have used `180.0` in place of `180`)

To convert degrees to radians, use this formula:

```
(degrees*M_PI)/180.0
```

Comment: Agreed! Nice work. I stopped looking as soon as I saw the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the '180/n' part is dividing integers. Try:

```
sin(180.0/n);
```

**Edit** as @sosborn correctly pointed, you are doing arithmetic among 'pointer to int', not ints themselves.

Comment: He edited his question so I am not sure anymore if he actually used pointers. Removing my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

***"huge numbers like -12425553 or 23082083."***

**pi** = n*(sin(180/**n**));
    
    *int *n; double *pi;*

---

Remember that you are trying to do this on pointers ! ;)
    
    It just work if you use values, check your "*".