# Sin x program dosn't work

Tags: c++, trigonometry

```
# include <iostream>
# include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count=1;
    double x;
    double sine, num, dem, sign, term;
    sine=0;
    sign = 1;

    cout << "Get x: ";
    cin >> x;
    num = x;
    dem = count;

    while ( count <= 10 )
    {
        term = (num/dem);
        sine = sine + term*sign;
        num = num*x*x;
        count = count + 2;
        dem = dem * count * (count-1);
        sign = -sign;
    }

    cout << "The result is: ";
    cout << sine;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code I wrote for sin x in C++, can someone point out my errors since the program doesn't calculate the correct value, I have try to debug for hours of time but my effort is kinda futile, I appreciate your help!Thanks!

*num=numerator, dem=denominator

Comment: Related: [Using sin() in a formula in xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11560279/335858).

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: What input have you tried? What output have you got? What output did you expect?

Comment: @n.m. I tried x=3.1416, it gave me the result 0.006981 instead of -7.34641e^-6

Comment: @Asus93 Chabge `count <= 10` to `count <= 100`

Comment: You have used an approximate formula and got an approximate result. Sounds good enough to me. If you need your results correct to the last significant digit, you need to use much more sophisticated methods.

Comment: @johnchen902 Wow, it worked!Can't believe it! I will update with u guys if I found any errors... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going out to 20 terms, not just 10.

And since the series converges more slowly when x is large, take x modulo 2π before you start.

Answer (score 0):

Polynomial approximations to sine etc. only really work for a narrow range of values. Using more terms, effectively a higher degree polynomial, can improve accuracy up to a point, but you soon get into increased rounding errors.

You need to pick a narrow domain to calculate using the series, and then reduce inputs outside that range to a value in the range with the same sine.

After you have done that, experiment with the number of terms.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, your program is right. Check in your regular calc for sin(3.1416) keep the value in radians. The value you got is for 3.1416 degrees.. And the formula works for radians

Comment: Thanks, when I changed my counter from 10 to 20, it worked for me. =)

Comment: Do you mean to say that you got 0.006981 for 3.1416?

Comment: yup, but when I changed the count to larger value, the result was accurate.